# Is there any flag in Webchat that indicate the bot has finished voicing out the message?

Tags: angular, botframework, web-chat

I am trying to enable the mic soon after voicing out the welcome message. I want to know if there is any flag that indicates the message has been voiced out by the bot. Right now, I am enabling the mic through click method by giving a timeout of 4 seconds. Which fails in some cases when the bot takes time to initialize and voice out the message. So in those cases, while the mic turns on, the message stops voicing out suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `renderWebChat()` flavor of Web Chat, then it's possible you can still capture the activities with the `channelData.speak` property via one of the middleware, such as `activityMiddleware`.

The `useActivities` hook is a nice feature because it presents a nice package of the processed activities. However, if you can't use the hook, then access them as I mentioned above. Just be aware that you will need to introduce processing logic of your own to filter and narrow them down as you need.

I mention above that "it's possible" to do this as I have only tested in a standard html page. I haven't tested this in an Angular project.

```js
const activityMiddleware = () => next => ( { activity, ...otherArgs } ) => {
  const { channelData } = activity;

  if (channelData && channelData.speak === true || channelData && channelData.speak === false) {
    console.log('MIDDLEWARE ACTIVITY ', activity)
  }

  return next( { activity, ...otherArgs });
}

[ ... ]

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine( {
      token: token
    } ),
    webSpeechPonyfillFactory: webSpeechPonyfillFactory,
    activityMiddleware: activityMiddleware
  },
  document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
);
```

[image]

Comment: Also answered in the BotFramework-WebChat GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3273#issuecomment-649105354).